# Sansevieria species specification needed

Tags: botany, species, species-identification

What are the botanical differences between the species S. parva and S. senegambica? Please highlight the main ones.
I have 2 groups of plants. One with label "Sansevieria dooneri" (a synonym of S. parva) and one with label "Sansevieria senegambica" and sadly both groups look awfully the same at first sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [this](http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/11492757#page/201/mode/1up) key to the genus. The differences between both species should become obvious when tracing back the decision tree. It seems that they can be distinguished mainly by the leaf size/shape of adult plants.

Comment: Thank you! I've searched in BHL, but didn't found this key. It would be useful. :)